# Inverse of Functions Containing Multiple "x"s

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say you had a function such as:
$$ x^3-2x+3 $$
Or even $x^x$
or something, in the same way, $x^2$ (for the most part) is the inverse of $x^{1/2}$, how would you, and what would you get if you inversed a polynomial? I can't figure out how to undo the function to get a close approximation to it's inverse. (In terms of x not y).

Is it possible that some functions cant be inverted?

Answer (score 1):

Some functions can't be inverted! In order for a graph in the plane to be a function of the $x-$axis, we must have that every $x-$input corresponds to some unique $y-$output.

Also, inverting a function of $x$ in the plane means flipping the picture across the line $y=x$. Can you see why some functions might not be invertible?[image]

Comment: Oh my bad, I don't think I was clear, I understand that in order for the inverse to be a function, all y values on the function must be unique, but I was referring to just an expression that would best approximate the inverse, whether or not its a function if that makes any sense. For example, no y values on the function sin(x) are unique, however it's inverse function is best approximated to arcsin(x) or how sqrt(x) is an approximate Inverse for x^2 even if undefined for negative numbers.  TLDR: asking for the closest approximate of an inverse function.

Comment: In general, there is no *closest* approximation. If you know some stuff about calculus, or if you just look at the graph and see that the *slope* of the picture around a certain point is not horizontal, then the inverse function theorem applies and tells us that, locally, the function is invertible. Getting approximations for this inverse is also done with calculus.